# My Kali upgrade fails - location of the log to find out the problem

Tags: kali-linux, logs, upgrade, dist-upgrade

Where is the log that tells me where the upgrade got to before it failed.

My current info:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2019.1
Codename:   n/a
```

Just trying to get to the latest build

Comment: How were you upgrading, and from what version to what version? (Please [edit] your question to include this. Do not reply here in the comments.)

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/apt`?

Comment: So how were you upgrading? (Command line? GUI? What action or command?)

Comment: Ive fixed it by manually installing each package. Would still be good to know if there is a log file that would show where it stopped. Will check /var/log/apt - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed log of `apt`-based package changes (including upgrades) is stored in `/var/log/apt/term.log`. Reading that will tell you how far the process got, and also why it failed.

`/var/log/apt/history.log`, which you can match up with `term.log` by looking at the entry timestamps, will tell you what `apt` command was run and what it tried to do.